# Play Framework: EntityManager is closed

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I have an endpoint that read data from the database. As a result, I have two DAO clases: DAO1 and DAO2.
In DAO1 I have something like this:

```
public MYDO1 get(Long id) {
    return em.find(MyDO1.class, id);
}
```

In DAO2 I have something like this:

```
public List<MyDO2> getSomething(Long idFromDO1) {
   CriteriaQuery<MyDO2> criteriaQuery= criteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyDO2.class);
   Root<MyDO2> root = criteriaQuery.from(MyDO2.class);
   criteriaQuery.select(root);
   Predicate p1 ...
   Predicate p2 ...

   criteriaQuery.where(myPredicates);

   Query query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
   return query.getResultsList();
}
```

Now, in my service class, I do a call on the two DAOs. At the first call everything works. At the second call however, I get this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed`

The stranger part is that I also have an endpoint for retrieving the MyDO1 entry that calls the same DAO and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The service class that did not work had @Singleton. Removing that solved the problem.

Comment: I don't really see how a properly designed singleton class is going to cause a closed entity manager to be reused. I wouldn't treat this as solved so quickly, for now you made the problem go away.